# What does `x[False]` do in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array `x = np.arange(6).reshape(3, 2)`.

What is the meaning of `x[False]`, or `x[np.asanyarray(False)]`? Both result in `array([], shape=(0, 3, 2), dtype=int64)`, which is unexpected.

I expected to get an `IndexError` because of an improperly sized mask, as from something like `x[np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.bool)]`.

This behavior *is* consistent for `x[True]` and `x[np.asanyarray(True)]`, as both result in an additional dimension: `array([[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]])`.

I am using numpy 1.13.1. It appears that the behavior has changed recently, so while it is nice to have answers for older versions, please mention your version in the answers.

**EDIT**

Just for completeness, I filed https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/9515 based on the commentary on this question.

**EDIT 2**

And closed it almost immeditely.

Comment: What NumPy version are you in?  I get `array([0, 1])` as a result.  And this is because `False` is treated as `0`, --> `x[0]` (in 1.11.3)

Comment: @BradSolomon It was changed in the last version: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/release.html#boolean-indexing-changes (*Boolean indexing into scalar arrays return a new 1-d array. This means that array(1)[array(True)] gives array([1]) and not the original array.*)

Comment: @BradSolomon. Version 1.13.1, `False` will be treated as an integer, unless you pass in a boolean matrix, as I have shown in my expected example. I am fine with the idea of `x[False] == x[0]`, but not so much with `x[np.array(False)] == x[0]`. Neither seems to be happening.

Comment: @ayhan: No, that's a different change.

Comment: @ayhan: The relevant part here is a bit higher up than the part you quoted: "Boolean scalars (including python True) are legal boolean indexes and never treated as integers."

Comment: @user2357112 Yes you are correct. I mixed them up.

Comment: Also, if these are the dimensions you're seeing, that looks like a bug to me. I think the dimensions are supposed to be (0, 2), not (0, 2, 3).

Comment: @user2357112. I think it may be. Looks like there's a `None` that got added into a slicing expression.

Comment: Hmm... the results of `numpy.nonzero` for 0-dimensional input doesn't really make sense, and the NumPy advanced indexing docs don't properly describe 0-dimensional boolean indexing. For example, `numpy.array(3)[False]` and `numpy.array(3)[numpy.nonzero(False)]` aren't consistent. I think we're running into fundamental limits on how far parts of this design can be generalized.

Comment: Your bug report gives a result shape of `(0, 3, 2)` instead of `(0, 2, 3)`. That makes more sense.

Comment: @user2357112. Thanks for the catch. Fixed

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's technically no requirement that the dimensionality of a mask match the dimensionality of the array you index with it. (In previous versions, there were even fewer restrictions, and you could get away with some extreme shape mismatches.)

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) describe boolean indexing as

> A single boolean index array is practically identical to x[obj.nonzero()] where, as described above, obj.nonzero() returns a tuple (of length obj.ndim) of integer index arrays showing the True elements of obj.

but `nonzero` is weird for 0-dimensional input, so this case is one of the ways that "practically identical" turns out to be not identical:

> the nonzero equivalence for Boolean arrays does not hold for zero dimensional boolean arrays.

NumPy has a special case for a 0-dimensional boolean index, motivated by the desire to have the following behavior:

```
In [3]: numpy.array(3)[True]
Out[3]: array([3])

In [4]: numpy.array(3)[False]
Out[4]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

I'll refer to a [comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/899d279c4ab9532d1dd122f754e536ee7aa75896/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L562) in the source code that handles a 0-dimensional boolean index:

```
if (PyArray_NDIM(arr) == 0) {
    /*
     * This can actually be well defined. A new axis is added,
     * but at the same time no axis is "used". So if we have True,
     * we add a new axis (a bit like with np.newaxis). If it is
     * False, we add a new axis, but this axis has 0 entries.
     */
```

While this is primarily intended for a 0-dimensional index to a 0-dimensional array, it also applies to indexing multidimensional arrays with booleans. Thus,

```
x[True]
```

is equivalent to `x[np.newaxis]`, producing a result with a new length-1 axis in front, and

```
x[False]
```

produces a result with a new axis in front of length 0, selecting no elements.

Comment: This is great. I will just check my masks using `np.array(mask, dtype=np.bool, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=1)`. That should remove the "weird" behavior.

Comment: Closed the issue.