# How does Ellipsis interact with index elements other than ints and slice objects?

Tags: python, numpy

The [NumPy indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) say that

> `Ellipsis` expand to the number of `:` objects needed to make a selection
>   tuple of the same length as `x.ndim`.

However, this seems to hold only when the other indexing arguments are ints and slice objects. For example, `None` doesn't seem to count towards the selection tuple length for the purposes of `Ellipsis`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.zeros([2, 2]).shape
(2, 2)
>>> numpy.zeros([2, 2])[..., None].shape
(2, 2, 1)
>>> numpy.zeros([2, 2])[:, None].shape
(2, 1, 2)
>>> numpy.zeros([2, 2])[:, :, None].shape
(2, 2, 1)
```

Similar odd effects can be observed with boolean indexes, which may count as multiple tuple elements or none at all.

How does NumPy expand `Ellipsis` in the general case?

Answer (score 0):

`Ellipsis` does expand to be equivalent to a number of `:`s, but that number is not always whatever makes the selection tuple length match the array's `ndim`. Rather, it expands to enough `:`s for the selection tuple to *use* every dimension of the array.

In most NumPy indexing, each element of the selection tuple matches up to some dimension of the original array. For example, in

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(9).reshape([3, 3])
>>> x[1, :]
array([3, 4, 5])
```

the `1` matches up to the first dimension of `x`, and the `:` matches up to the second dimension. The `1` and the `:` *use* those dimensions.

---

Indexing elements don't always *use* exactly one array dimension, though. If an indexing element corresponds to no input dimensions, or multiple input dimensions, that indexing element will *use* that many dimensions of the input. For example, `None` creates a new dimension in the output not corresponding to any dimension of the input. `None` doesn't use an input dimension, which is why

```
numpy.zeros([2, 2])[..., None]
```

expands to

```
numpy.zeros([2, 2])[:, :, None]
```

instead of `numpy.zeros([2, 2])[:, None]`.

---

Similarly, a boolean index *uses* a number of dimensions corresponding to the number of dimensions of the boolean index itself. For example, a [boolean scalar index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493270/what-does-xfalse-do-in-numpy) uses none:

```
>>> x[..., False].shape
(3, 3, 0)
>>> x[:, False].shape
(3, 0, 3)
>>> x[:, :, False].shape
(3, 3, 0)
```

And in the common case of a boolean array index with the same shape as the array it's indexing, the boolean array will *use* every dimension of the other array, and inserting a `...` will do nothing:

```
>>> x.shape
(3, 3)
>>> (x < 5).shape
(3, 3)
>>> x[x<5]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> x[..., x<5]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

---

If you want to see the source code that handles `...` expansion and *used* dimension calculation, it's in the NumPy github repository in the [`prepare_index`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.3/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L143) function under `numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c`. Look for the `used_ndim` variable.